# On button click, increase displayed number qt qml

Tags: qt, qml

I'm trying to get a displayed number to change when a button is clicked. How would I do that?

Here is my QML code

```
Button {
   id:button
   x:232
   y:250
   width:18
   height:18
   // Makes button have a transparent background
   palette {
   button: "transparent"
   }

   Image {
     anchors.fill: Button
     source:"Images/image.png"

     }
     // Moves rectangle down, on button click
     onClicked: rectangle.y-=10

     }

     Text{
      text: qsTr("12.0")
     }
```

I want the number 12 to increase each time the button is clicked

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare a [property](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/propertybinding.html) of type int, visible for both Text and Button items.

So an example code can be:

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0

Window {
   id: rootWindow
   visible: true
   width: 300; height: 300

   property int displayValue: 12

   Text {
      id: displayTextId
      anchors.left: addOneButtonId.right

      text: displayValue.toString() //more clear if you explicit the parent rootWindow.displayValue.toString()
   }

   Button {
      id: addOneButtonId

      text: "Add 1"
      onClicked: {
         rootWindow.displayValue += 1
      }
   }
}
```

Alternatively, the property can be declared local to the Text element (so defined inside it), but pay attention, because a property is visible only for its child.

By the way, your code is full of error. If you want to create a button, that contains an image and a text, the best way is that you create a [Rectangle](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-rectangle.html) object and define a [Mouse area](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-mousearea.html) inside it.

The code structure should be like:

```
Rectangle {
   id: root
   property int number: 12

   width: 100; height: 50
   color: "transparent"
   border.width: 1
   border.color: "black"

   Image { id: imageId }
   Text { id: textId; text: root.number.toString()  }

   MouseArea {
      anchors.fill: parent

      onClicked: {
         root.y += 10 // shift the y position down
         root.number += 1
      }
   }
}
```